# I want to highlight a question as a really solid question IMO

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Which major solar system body could most realistically be artificial?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74441/which-major-solar-system-body-could-most-realistically-be-artificial)

This is to me one of the best questions ever asked on WB. It is exactly on topic, draws on the community to ask a precise hypothetical, it is short without fluffy backstory to interfere with comprehension, and it is answerable. I'm highlighting it here so as many people as possible take a moment to read it and give it good answers.

Comment: But it asjs for “best” and “which one”, so isn't that POB?

Comment: Isn't this what the bounty system is for, or am I missing what you're intending?

Comment: No, not POB. There is judgement, but it is based on meeting an objective standard.

Comment: @andon good point! But I can't seem to add bounty yet. I think there's a waiting period.

Comment: @SRM Yeah, it's something like two days or so. Not terrible

Comment: Maybe 72 hours.

Comment: Two days last time I checked. But surely, it might have changed.

Comment: @SRM I disagree with you that this a candidate for a "best question". The topic is technically relevant but far off from how I perceive the concept of "building a world". The connection is only that the **words** "building a world" happen to match. It is not at all precise, since asking for **probabilities** is by its very nature asking for something imprecise. It is shot, much too short and while it lacks fluff it also lacks substance. I do not see this question as anything special that deserves extra attention.

Answer (score 1):

The designed way to do this is to set a bounty with "this question deserves more attention" bounty reason.

I think you may safely assume that most meta visitors already know most of the recent questions, and others are here just to solve one specific issue and won't be interested in your post.

Comment: I agree that the best way to draw attention to a question is through a bounty. However, I don't think one should assume that most meta visitors already know most of the recent questions - I, for one, don't read all questions as I don't always have the time to do so; since I have to pick questions, I choose those which title catches my eye and skip the rest. Meta is, on the other hand, much slower and easier to read all recent questions. While most visitors probably do read the most recent questions, there is likely a significant portion which does not and, thus, does not know all of them.